# Passing Objects and Proper Program Architecture - Python

Tags: python, oop, architecture

I am creating a python script that executes a series of tests that writes and reads information to and from a CAN bus network. I'm using python-can and cantools packages. I've managed to transmit and receive data with small functions individually without issue.

The problem I am having is creating the proper "Pythonic" script architecture that allows my script to use all functions, instances and variables between modules.

**Intended architecture goal:**

- `main.py` - contains CAN bus transmit/receive functions, performs initialization and cycles through each test case located in the `test_case.py` module.
- `test_case.py`  - stores all test cases (each test case is a
  stand alone function). Each test case must be an isolated function so that if one test needs to be removed or a new test added the script won't break. Additionally, there will likely be dozens maybe hundreds of test cases.
  So I'd like to keep them isolated to one module for code cleanliness.
- `test_thresholds.py` - would keep all the pass/fail threshold variables
  that each test case in `test_case.py` will refer to.

**Problem/Question #1:**

`main.py` instantiates a CAN bus object `bus = can.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)` this object is required for the transmit/receive functions. Because the transmit and recieve functions are within `main.py` this wasn't a problem until I tried to execute a test case in the `test_case.py` module which references the transmit/receive functions in `main.py`

Once I attempted to execute a test case an error occurred stating that the `receive()` function being called from the `test_case.py` module `NameError: name 'bus' is not defined` I understand this as `test_case.py` does not know what the `bus` instance is. This problem also occurs with my `can` instances. I have `from main import *` in my `test_case.py` I know this is bad but I am not sure how else  `test_cases.py` will use the transmit and receive functions along with the `bus` and `can` instances

***How can I share that instances between modules? What are the best practices here?*** I have tried to go over several posts on StackOverflow regarding passing objects ( I think thats what my problem is) but none of them seem to answer what I'm looking for.

**Problem/Question #2:**

***Is my architecture design acceptable? I'm new to designing larger scripts and I want to make sure I am doing it effectively/proper so that it can scale.***

**Code:**
I've cut down a lot of my code to make it more readable here. It may not run if you try it.

main.py module

```
import can
import cantools
import test_cases.test_cases  # import all test cases
import time


# sending a single CAN message
def single_send(message):
    try:
        bus.send(message)
    except can.CanError:
        print("Message NOT sent")


# receive a message and decode payload
def receive(message, signal):
    _counter = 0
    try:
        while True:
            msg = bus.recv(1)
            try:
                if msg.arbitration_id == message.arbitration_id:
                    message_data = db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data)
                    signal_data = message_data.get(signal)
                    return signal_data
            except AttributeError:
                _counter += 1
                if _counter == 5:
                    print("CAN Bus InActive")
                    break
    finally:
        if _counter == 5:
            # reports false if message fails to be received
            return False

def main():
    for name, tests in test_cases.test_cases.__dict__.items():
        if name.startswith("tc") and callable(tests):
            tests()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bus = can.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)
    db = cantools.db.load_file('C:\\Users\\tw\\Desktop\\dbc_file.dbc')
    verbose_log = open("verbose_log.txt", "a")
    main()
    bus.shutdown()
    verbose_log.close()
```

test_case.py module

```
from test_thresholds.test_thresholds import *
from main import *  # to use the single_send and receive functions in main 

def tc_1():
    ct = receive(0x300, 'ct_signal')  # this is where the issue occurs. receive expects the bus instance
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x303, data=1)
    if (ct > ct_min) and (ct < ct_max):
        verbose_log.write("PASS")
    else:
        verbose_log.write("FAIL")
```

test_thresholds.py module

```
ct_min = 4.2 
ct_max = 5.3
```

Windows 10, PyCharm, Python 3.8

Comment: `bus` is defined within `if __name__ == "__main__":`. This `if` block only gets executed when you run the file directly and **not** when you import it, when you import the module `bus` is not defined. You need to define your variables outside of this `if` block or add parameters to your functions that take `bus`, `db`, etc

Comment: This issue with that is when I place the `bus` instance out of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` I get the following error: `can.interfaces.pcan.pcan.PcanError: A PCAN Channel has not been initialized yet or the initialization process has failed`

Comment: If you have working code you want to improve, then you probably have a good question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). You will probably find more people willing to do an in-depth code review of your code there.

Comment: @Unatiel thank you. I did not know such a place existed

Comment: _I have `from main import *` in my `test_case.py` I know this is bad but I am not sure how else  `test_cases.py` will use the transmit and receive functions along with the `bus` and `can` instances_ You could explicitly import those, or qualify them with the module name, no?

Comment: What do you mean by, _qualify them with the module name_? @AMC

Comment: @Tim51 You would `import main`, and then write `main.bus` and `main.can`.